# Android LogCat and Codegist CRest

Tags: android, logging, logcat

I'm using http://crest.codegist.org/ to communicate with server and I want to log responses and requests with android LogCat.

How can I configure  CRest (or System) to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

- execute a command on your connected device:

  ```
  MBP:~ roman$adb shell setprop log.tag.CodeGist VERBOSE
  ```
- set the same property programmatically using the [System.setProperty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method